# Bitbucket git "unable to access 404"

Tags: git, proxy, bitbucket, pull

I'm trying to get the latest commits from BitBucket with git, but git bash is showing next text:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/project.git/': Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT

I enter the following command:

```
$ git pull origin develop
```

This error appeared after IP Bitbucket updating.
Please, help me. I cann't work because this error show up always.

Updated:

> git config -l

```
    core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
core.autocrlf=true
core.excludesfile=C:\Users\MyName\Documents\gitignore_global.txt
http.proxy=http://www.google.com:80
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
:...skipping...
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
core.autocrlf=true
core.excludesfile=C:\Users\MyName\Documents\gitignore_global.txt
http.proxy=http://www.google.com:80
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/project.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Is the URL correct? Do you have appropriate permissions?

Comment: @Dyno Yes, url is absolutly corrent. I do, because I'm owner.

Comment: What is the output of `git config -l` ?

Comment: please format that as code and edit it into the question itself. This is very difficult to read.

Comment: @Dyno Updated question

Comment: Why are you proxying through google.com:80?

Comment: @JimRedmond I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I remove http.proxy in git global settings.